# Is there any point to using value-initialisation vs default initialisation syntax for POD in C++

Tags: c++, initialization, default-constructor

Are there any reasons to prefer to do

```
int A {};
```

instead of

```
int A;
```

as a rule in your code? I guess it could be argued that, for the former, it makes it explicit to anyone reading your code that you meant to call the default constructor rather than just forgot to call a different one.

Comment: Depends on if you want `A` to be initialised with `0` or left indeterminate. [Default initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization): _"...otherwise, no initialization is performed: the objects with automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) contain indeterminate values...."_

Comment: @RichardCritten Do both not just call the default constructor?

Comment: Not for scalar types ie `int`

Comment: @jabaa `int` is a POD: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType

Comment: Non-class types don't have constructors. `{}` zeroes the number, otherwise it would be initialized. `{}` has a similar effect on some classes, zeroing the members that would otherwise be uninitialized (the class either must have no user-declared constructors, or a `=default`ed default constructor).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat. If I have my own `class T`, where I explicitly `=default` the default constructor, can there be difference between `T a;` and `T b {};`

Comment: Yes if you have member `int a;` which is either `int a;` or `int a{};`

Comment: @TCD we can only answer the question as asked.  Please post a [mcve] for the question you want answering.  The code in the question is for scalar/POD types not non-POD class types.

Comment: @TCD Yes, as I said in that case `{}` would zero the members that would otherwise be uninitialized. Oh, and one more condition: `=default` has to be inside of the class body, not outside on a function definition.